# Selectpicker in Bootstrap5

Tags: bootstrap-5, bootstrap-selectpicker

I have been attempting to create a live search select using Bootstrap 5, but unfortunately, I am facing difficulties in getting it to function properly.

I kindly request assistance from anyone who might be able to lend a hand in resolving this issue.

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>SelectPicker</title>
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    
    <body>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="card mt-4">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h6>Select Picker</h6>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <select class="form-select selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
              <option selected value="">Type here to find contents</option>
              <option value="1">Option 1</option>
              <option value="2">Option 2</option>
              <option value="3">Option 3</option>
              <option value="4">Option 4</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you're including bootstrap-select.js. Also bootstrap 5.3.2 is not currently working with selectpicker: https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/issues/2846

Also, you should add more detail to your ticket. Saying you 'can't get it working' isn't enough for others to help you.